# clearing of messages on reset button[IceFaces]

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using Icefaces and I want to clear all my Ice:messages(validation Messages) on click of reset button.I am using type="reset" in my Ice:commandButton without any actionListener.
Can anyone help me plzz..
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Either put your messages in the form (this attribute is ment to reset a form) or solve the validation errors and refresh the page.

Comment: My every messages is in the form itself...what do you mean putting it in the form??